# Teamviewer vpn alternatives

Tags: raspbian, vpn, teamviewer

I have a pi and a pc, both connected to the Internet but not visible to it.
Normally I would use TeamViewer to connect both and use the vpn feature to get a Bridge.

Now my Problem is that Raspbian teamviewer don't has the vpn feature.
I found many other vpn's with this feature but the Problem is that I don't want to be visible to the Internet and because of that cant directly connect to a IP address. Also the IP addresses are changing so the Connection over a Code via TeamViewer was perfect.

I there any other vpn service that does this kind of vpn that TeamViewer has? (Like from)

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer works because everything is done through their third party servers. The teamviewer program will make a connection to their servers from within your network, giving the ability to connect to that device from outside of your network.

Easiest way to achieve what you are doing is with DDNS/port forwarding. (I know, you don't want to do this) but without coding something up yourself, it's not possible.

The way around this is to make your rpi (or router) a `VPN endpoint`. That way, you can just VPN to your home network from outside you are and you will have full access to your LAN (and your pi device). This will still require port forwarding, but you can choose any port you like essentially.

Other than that, there's no easy way to achieve it. There are some alternatives that work in a similar way as TeamViewer (paid and free), but probably would not have VPN feature, or it would work in another way, like AnyDesk, LogMeIn.

Comment: I surmise Teamviewer can perhaps act as a broker to enable two systems behind NAT to establish a direct connection by exchanging informations through the broker if "conditions" are good (see for example [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) ). Anyway, as answered, there's the need of a 3rd party. It could even be one's hosted own VPS/VM.